# In Schengen visa application, should I include details of my friend who will be spending time with me?

Tags: schengen, applications, schengen-visas

I live in the US (non-US citizen) and am planning to visit Europe for tourism.

I am applying for a Schengen visa in the French Consulate in Washington DC.

A friend of mine who lives in Singapore also is planning to join me for the trip. He also needs a visa and will be applying (a day before me) from the French Consulate in Singapore. He will of course be flying in to Europe from Singapore and me from the US. We will be meeting directly in France and touring together.

**Should I mention him in the cover letter that I am drafting for my visa application ?**

Currently I have all our itinerary listed down in the letter, but the hotel reservations I am including are for two people (room with double beds), so I am thinking if the visa folks might notice that...

Comment: What for? Is he your dependent? Are you financing his trip? Is he hosting you? From a consular officers perspective how does he affect your eligibility or lac thereof for a Schengen visa? To me there is no point whatsoever.

Comment: Nope, he is not my dependent nor am I going to finance his trip. But the visa folks say they need all details about the trip, so I was wondering if travel companions are included in that.

Answer (score 1):

Since that person is not:

- A French resident
- Your dependent
- Your financial sponsor (or vice-versa)

There is no need to mention him on the cover letter. Simply state your plans as-is without going into too much detail.